# Can I convert a Flask application into an executable file that runs on Windows like an .exe file?

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I've got a python project for a downloadable software I plan on distributing and it's a windows application. I an using pyinstaller for bundling it into one .exe file. I have followed https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/building-python-files-into-stand-alone-executables-using-pyinstaller and extracted:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py file is:

```
from __init__ import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

But every time it gives me it displays the error: Failed to execute the script start.

After that, I have tried https://www.quora.com/Can-I-convert-a-Flask-application-into-an-executable-file-that-runs-on-Windows-like-an-exe-file as seems to be the best solution but this also gave the error.

```
C:\Users\Prachi Jain-GGN\Project>pyinstaller --onefile --windowed wsgi.spec
133 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
133 INFO: Python: 3.6.5 (conda)
137 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
147 INFO: UPX is not available.
149 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Prachi Jain-GGN\\Project',
 'C:\\Users\\Prachi Jain-GGN\\Project']
161 INFO: checking Analysis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Prachi Jain-GGN\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\prachi jain-ggn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "wsgi.spec", line 37, in <module>
    a.datas += extra_datas("static")
NameError: name 'extra_datas' is not defined
```

I have prepared the eggs on the window platform using: 
https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers and

```
sudo python setup.py bdist
```

Only eggs were downloaded and not the setup of the application.

Comment: You could try this https://medium.com/@KelvinMwinuka/converting-flask-web-app-into-a-cross-platform-desktop-app-6692bf0720c